# __init__ argument error when importing

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm running Python 3.5 64-bit version on a Windows 7 machine.

I have a Python class whose constructor requires two arguments, self and an instance of another class:

```
class Level3_CoilsSet(Recordset):
    def __init__(self, connection):
        super().__init__(connection)
        self.DefaultTableName = 'coils'
        self._keyFields.append('coils_key')
        self._defaultedFields.append('coils_key')
```

Here is the top of the `Recordset` constructor (the only things left out are initialization of variables):

```
from adodb_pyodbc import Connection
from adodb_pyodbc import Field

class Recordset:
    def __init__(self, connection: Connection = None):
        self.Conn = connection
        self.DefaultTableName = None
        self.WhereClause = None
        self.OrderClause = None
```

The `Connection` class's constructor is nothing special:

```
class Connection:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pyConnection = None
        self.AutoCommit = True
```

The `Connection` and `Recordset` classes reside in a folder in site-packages, along with an empty `__init__.py` file. 
When I run this, I get the following error:

```
C:\Python35\python.exe "C:/Customers/Nucor Crawfordsville/Scripts/64 bit/Testing/cpsa_simulator.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Customers/Nucor Crawfordsville/Scripts/64 bit/Testing/cpsa_simulator.py", line 8, in <module>
    from Level3_CoilsSet import Level3_CoilsSet
  File "C:\Customers\Nucor Crawfordsville\Scripts\64 bit\Testing\Level3_CoilsSet.py", line 3, in <module>
    class Level3_CoilsSet(Recordset):
TypeError: module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

What is going on here?  Why is an `__init__()` method being called during import?  What three arguments are given to it?  The callback list given in PyCharm does not point to anything helpful.  I had the same code working successfully in a different directory structure, with the three files in the adodb_pyodbc folder in the same folder as my main file, but now that I moved them into a folder under site-packages, it fails.

Comment: It seems likely that your `Recordset` import is wrong.

Comment: I guess that `Recordset` is the name of a module, not the name of a class.

Comment: Hmmm...  Quite possible.  It is definitely the name of a class, but it might also be the name of a module.  Many thanks for your reply.